# create views in filemaker

Tags: view, filemaker

I am trying to make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9bp6.jpg) in Filemaker Database views.

The database will contain employees and projects. There need to be two combined views. One displaying the list of employees and which projects they are on in which week and by which percentage. The other one displaying the list of projects and which employees are on it in which week by which percentage. For each employee and each project there need to be a sum of percentages for all assigned projects / employees.
I have made three tables in my database:

1. employee
2. projects
3. employee_on_projects

Now I want to create these views. Can anybody tell me how to do this from scratch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad for this forum, which usually deals with a particular programming problem. You are better off taking it to a FileMaker users dedicated forum. Try to search on FileMaker crosstab reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileMaker is not a good tool for creating cross-tab reports, as it has no native functionality to build these. It has to be done manually. Do a search on cross tab reporting in FileMaker and you will get some ideas.
Traditionally you need relationships and fields to hold and display your data.

On the top of my head, in this case I would probably use merge variables for displaying progress and other calculated data to avoid having fields for all those weeks. A script would gather the data using ExecuteSQL and calculate the variables. The whole thing could even be generated in HTML and displayed in a web viewer.
This way you should get away without too many relationships and fields.
If you want a simpler, but more cluttered solution, you could go with regular fields for all 53 weeks and use a sub summary report. Each field could be set up with ExecuteSQL if possible, to avoid having a relationship for each period.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply.

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to upvote or accept answer :)